# Select a cell after using "find" tool

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to select a cell after using the find tool, but it's not working.

Hello

My plan is to, from the first cell, find a cell with "b1 -" in it, select it, offset 11 cells to the right, and select the 4x4 square in it, and copy it. I have this at the moment and it's not working. THe error is 424, "obligatory object"

```
Sub Macro4()
'
' Macro4 Macro
'
' Atalho do teclado: Ctrl+a
'
    Range("A1").Select
    Cells.Find(What:="b1 -", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
        :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
        False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    Cell.Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 11).Range("A1:B4").Select
    Selection.Copy
End Sub
```

Any help is appreciated very much

Comment: Remove Cell.Select line.

Comment: @CetinBasoz Oh... oops. lol 

Thanks you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. When using `Find` always good to check first that the value is found otherwise you will have an error to deal with.

```
Sub Macro4()

Dim r As Range

Set r = Cells.Find(What:="b1 -", After:=Range("A1"), LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                   LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                   MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
If Not r Is Nothing Then 'check found first
    r.Offset(0, 11).Resize(2, 2).Select
    'no need to select, i.e. just "r.Offset(0, 11).Resize(2, 2).copy" is better
End If

End Sub
```

Also selecting things is not advisable -
[How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Answer (score 1):

### Reference a Range According to a Found Cell

```vb
Sub Macro4()
'
' Macro4 Macro
'
' Atalho do teclado: Ctrl+a
'
    
    Const FIRST_CELL_IN_COLUMN As String = "A2"
    Const CONTAINS As String = "b1 -"
    Const COLUMN_OFFSET As Long = 11
    Const SIZE_ROWS As Long = 4
    Const SIZE_COLS As Long = 4
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    
    Dim prg As Range, fCell As Range
    
    With ws.Range(FIRST_CELL_IN_COLUMN)
        Set prg = .Resize(ws.Rows.Count - .Row + 1)
        With prg
            Set fCell = .Find(CONTAINS, .Cells(.Cells.Count), xlFormulas, xlPart)
        End With
    End With
    
    If fCell Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "The string """ & CONTAINS & """ is not contained in any cell " _
            & "of the range """ & prg.Address(0, 0) & """ of worksheet """ _
            & ws.Name & """!", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim rg As Range:
    Set rg = fCell.Offset(, COLUMN_OFFSET).Resize(SIZE_ROWS, SIZE_COLS)
    
    Debug.Print fCell.Address(0, 0), rg.Address(0, 0)
    
    rg.Copy
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You're nearly there. Here are a few adjustments for you.  :)

```
Sub Test()
    Cells.Find(What:="b1 -", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
        :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
        False, SearchFormat:=False).Offset(0, 11).Range("A1:B4").Copy
End Sub
```